# DML not allowed on Network

Tags: error, dml, update, community

My requirement needs to change the "from email address" for the welcome mail that is sent from  a community after a new user is registered. But this needs to be done dynamically based on some conditions.

For this I have written the following snippet of code.

```
    network n;
    n=[Select Id, EmailSenderAddress, NewSenderAddress from network limit 1]; // This is working fine
    n.NewSenderAddress='abc@xyz.com';
    update n;//Error on this line
```

I am not sure why is this throwing error "**DML not allowed on Network**".

There are no proper examples available.

The documentations available are-
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_network.htm

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_customize_email.htm&language=en_US

Can someone please help me in understanding and resolving this issue? Thanks!

## Edit

I am sharing a dummy code here explaining what I am trying to do:

```
public class xyz {
public String createUser(String emailAddress, String firstName, String lastName, String phNumber, String accountId){
    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.FirstName = firstName;
    newUser.LastName = lastName;
    newUser.Username = emailAddress;
    newUser.Email = emailAddress;
    newUser.Phone = phNumber;
    
    network n;
    n=[Select Id, EmailSenderAddress, NewSenderAddress from network limit 1]; // This is working fine
    n.NewSenderAddress='abc@xyz.com';
    update n;//Error on this line
    
    String userId;
    try{
        userId = Site.createPortalUser(newUser, accountId, null, true);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('error');
    }
    return userId;
  }
}
```

Comment: did you check if you or the user under which this code is running have the required permissions to create/setup communities ?

Comment: I have the permission, so essentially i should be able to save the controller atleast. The controller is not getting saved in the first place.

Comment: can you share your complete controller code.. r u doing this in a constructor ?

Comment: I have added a demo code block which is similar to what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say its either a bug in salesforce or a gap in salesforce docs.

I just tried the code in Developer Console - anonymous window and getting the same error.

```
Network n =[Select Id, EmailSenderAddress, NewSenderAddress from Network limit 1];
n.NewSenderAddress='abc@xyz.com';
update n;
```

[image]

The [Object specification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_network.htm) says update is possible and the [list of SObjects not supporting DML](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_dml_objects.htm) is not listing Network object which means DML / Update is possible on Network object.

You should raise a case with salesforce and see what they can do with this.

Comment: Thanks. And can you suggest me any other workaround?